# Java: "attempting to assign weaker access privilege error" (Compiling JDK 1.6 Source with 1.8)

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, java-6

Using Gradle, we are trying to compile legacy Java code, which was developed for JDK 1.6 with a JDK 1.8 compiler.
At some point the compilation process quits with the error

> attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

(The cause of the error itself is obvious: we have a method in an abstract class, which is declared *public*, but the implementing class declares it as *protected*.)

Using JDK 1.6 for compiling, we never had any issues with this.
Now for several reasons, we have to compile our code with Java 8, having us run into this issue.

We already tried project setting `-PsourceCompatibility=1.6` (also `-PtargetCompatibility=1.8`) when building, without effect.

At the moment, refactoring the whole product code (expecting more and similar errors to follow) is no option, so we are looking for a solution to build the old code with the new JDK.

Any help for this?

Comment: "we never had any issues with this". But you should have had them. This was always forbidden, in every version of Java.

Comment: Changing `public` to `protected` (or vice versa) isn't a significant refactoring, even if you get more of these errors.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't compiling against a different version of the class that was in a jar, or something? This sounds more like classpath hell than something so fundamental to Java that it got fixed in Java *8*.

Comment: Especially with "we never had any issues with this", this sounds worth investigating. I'll have an very close look....

Comment: I only remember older compilers being lax with `static` methods, which has been fixed and is the reason why `-source 1.6` wouldn’t help then, as the rules didn’t change and bug compatibility is not attempted. But I never heard of cases where overriding a `public abstract` method with a `protected` method was possible.

Answer (score 4):

The only explanation to the fact that your system used to work with Java 1.6 is that the method access in the superclass has been changed to `public` without recompiling the subclass. Lowering accessibility in a subclass has been prohibited from the beginning.

[Java Language Specification 1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/jls3.pdf) provides this explanation on page 344:

> if the package points defines the `class Point`:
>
> ```
> package points;
> public class Point {
>     public int x, y;
>     protected void print() {
>         System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> used by the Test program:
>
> ```
> class Test extends points.Point {
>     protected void print() {
>         System.out.println("Test");
>     }
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Test t = new Test();
>         t.print();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> then these classes compile and Test executes to produce the output:
>
> ```
> Test
> ```
>
> If the method `print` in class `Point` is changed to be `public`, and then only the `Point` class is recompiled, and then executed with the previously existing binary for `Test` then no linkage error occurs, even though it is improper, at compile time, for a public method to be overridden by a protected method (**as shown by the fact that the class `Test` could not be recompiled using this new `Point` class unless print were changed to be `public`**.) (emphasis added)

If you must re-create the exact behavior with Java 1.8 compiler, change accessibility in the superclass to `protected`, compile the superclass and subclass, then change accessibility in the superclass back to `public`, and compile only the superclass. However, at this point I would strongly recommend changing the subclass to provide proper accessibility.